# Text overflows beyond div occasionally in Chrome 43

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a basic block(purple) that has some text inside it of variable length. The div is position relative and is also responsive so its width etc is in %.

Some of our users on Chrome latest (v43.0.2357.65) and WinXP see the text overflows to the edge of the purple box. This happens on a whim so its hard to reproduce. I am trying to fix the CSS so that text does not overflow. I have a max-width and break-word property too on the div that contains the text.

The site is in dutch.

[image: screenshot of text overflowing]

```
<div class="mt-landing__section-notification">
<div class="mt-landing__section-notification__info-icon icon-info"></div>
                <div class="mt-landing__section-notification__close-icon"></div>
                <div class="mt-landing__section-notification__content">
                    <div class="mt-landing__section-notification__message">
                        This is where the text is. 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the CSS on the outermost div and the one containing the text :

```
.mt-landing__section-notification {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 64.5%;
    background-color: #411E4E;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
}
 .mt-landing__section-notification__message {
     line-height: 24px;
     margin-top: -3px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     max-width: 100%;
}
 .mt-landing__section-notification__content {
     margin: 0px 50px; 
  }
  .mt-landing__section-notification__info-icon {
       width: 50px;
       float: left;
       font-size: 24px;
  }
  .info-icon {
      font-family: mt-icons;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-variant: normal;
      text-transform: none;
      line-height: 1;
   }
   .info-icon::before {
        content: '\e617';
    }
```

Any ideas why text is overflowing ?

Comment: Can you paste the whole string you're using inside the div?

Comment: Here it is "Heeft u vanaf 23 mei een abonnementenwijziging doorgegeven? Door een systeemstoring kan he zijn dat deze wijziging nog niet is verwerkt. Wij hopen dit zo spoedig mogelijk te herstellen. Excuses." However I must mention this string is dynamic, it is set via a sort of a admin interface which ends up as a server side variable on the html template.  I have experienced this issue for different texts too.

Comment: Where does the icon on the left come from?

Comment: Your CSS is correct, as @BenPhilipp said, maybe the issue is caused from the left icon that is "pushing" everything to the right.

Comment: My icon is just a icon font, I define the font-family to the custom font and the content value in a psuedo element.
    icon-info {
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
     }
     .icon-info:before {
         content: "\e617";
        }

Comment: I always increase the `padding-left` whenever I need to do something like this, and use the icon as a background-image, like so: [http://www.grafik-wunder.de/klafo/forum](http://www.grafik-wunder.de/klafo/forum); this goes along with `box-sizing: border-box;` beautifully, and also allows for easy variations for mobile views (try resizing the window below 360px)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your info-icon might be the culprit here.

either
a) Set the icon to `position:absolute` and the container to `position:relative`, which will take the icon out of the flow, so it won't push the text to the right,

or
b)
maybe use the icon as a background-image. Simply increase the `padding-left` of the container and add it as a background-image. I find this to be the easiest way to keep things in order, whilst still flexible and responsive:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/s3xc3nro/

```css
.mt-landing__section-notification {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 64.5%;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
}
.mt-landing__section-notification__message {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.icon-info{
background: url(http://www.grafik-wunder.de/klafo/images/info.png)  #411E4E no-repeat 10px center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="mt-landing__section-notification  icon-info">
    <div class="mt-landing__section-notification__close-icon"></div>
    <div class="mt-landing__section-notification__content">
        <div class="mt-landing__section-notification__message">This is where the text is.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add that the icon-info class also has the following css.
mt-landing__section-notification__info-icon {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
}
Dont you think this should not interfere with the text on right. 

also therer is a margin on
 .mt-landing_section-notification__content {
   margin: 0px 50px;
}

Comment: Added all the css talked about in the comments in the original question to make it more clear. Thanks